# Android SMS handling

Tags: android, database, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-contentprovider

I am just wondering about how android handles sms when it receives them. More precisely my question is when the android phone receives a sms message, which application saves the message to the mmssms database? Is this done by the OS or by the native sms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving messages is handled by the OS. That's why you can get them from a 3rd party application.

Comment: What? Read it again, I said "That's why you *can* get them from a 3rd party application."

Comment: I am very sorry for having misread your comment. Makes more sense now. Thank you very much for your indication.